# Position Angular $modalInstance above specific div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a $modalInstance. I want the modal to display over a particular div. I know that I can use `window-class`, but beyond that, I am not sure how to set the position of the modal above a certain div.

Any ideas?

EDIT

```
this.showRetiredModal = function () {
        /*var modalInstance = */$modal.open({
            template: $templateCache.get('states/retire/retiremodal.html'),
            controller: 'RetireModalController',
            size: 1000,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            resolve: {
                birthDate: function () {
                    return _this.participantInfo.birthDate;
                },
                homeController: function () {
                    return _this;
                }
            }
        }).rendered.then(function () {
            // Grab target element
            var element = document.querySelector('.accordionIconWidth');
            // Get target position and size
            var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            // Grab modal element
            var modal = document.querySelector('.modal-dialog');

            // Set style 
            modal.style.margin = 0;
            modal.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
            modal.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
            modal.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
        });

    };
```

Comment: a modal would generally overlay the whole viewport...are you sure you are not looking for some other component like popover

Comment: Well it sits about 25 percent down from the top of the screen by default. What I am looking for is to get it down maybe 50 or 60 percent. But that percent is dynamically calculated right before the mdoal is displayed.

Comment: Okay, can't say about positioning above a particular div, but you can write a directive to change the margin top dynamically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this on the dynamicly when the dialog is opened you'll need to wait for the modal to be appended to the DOM. There's a promise in the modalinstance for that called `rendered`. Once resolved, grab target and modal elements from the DOM, calculate the targets position and apply it to the modal element:

```
// Initialize
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'modal.html',
    controller: 'modal'
// Wait for render
}).rendered.then(function() {
    // Grab target element
    var element = document.querySelector('.well'),
        // Get target position and size
        rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
        // Grab modal element
        modal = document.querySelector('.modal-dialog');

    // Set style 
    modal.style.margin = 0;
    modal.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
    modal.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
    modal.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vSTKm?p=preview

Comment: I keep getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined when I try to do this

Comment: Erhmz, i'm assuming here that you're using a ui-bootstrap modal. Right?

Comment: Ok, added a example on Plunker to my answer

Comment: Perfect, most helpful

Comment: Ok, working for you now? If not please add a testcase on JSFiddle or Plunker to your question.